# How to account for all whitespace (spaces, tabs, new lines) in regexp_substr() method?

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I have the following code snippet in SQL to select the next piece of text after `ABC DEF` that's of variable length:

`SELECT trim('ABC DEF ' FROM regexp_substr(my_field, 'ABC DEF ([^ ]+)')) FROM my_table`

Sample Data:

```
'{random text here}           ABC DEF          {my_variable_length_keyword} {random text here}'
```

Expected Output:
`{my_variable_length_keyword}`

While this works, it only accounts for cases where there is one space after `ABC DEF`. How would I deal with cases where there are tabs, new lines, or multiple spaces before the next word?

I've tried:

`SELECT trim('ABC DEF ' FROM regexp_substr(my_field, 'ABC DEF\s+([^ ]+)')) FROM my_table`

But this doesn't yield any result.

Can someone please help me out with this? Thank you!

Comment: Please add actual text as sample data, rather than placeholders.  We can't write a regex using what you added above.

Comment: I thought it was best to add a minimum reproducible example. The regex should technically still work with what I've given

Comment: OK... you want to capture the next non whitespace term immediately after `ABC DEF`, is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: In java one would need to write `\\s+` as the backslash escapes in a string. That could be the case here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use any lookarounds, nor do you need to trim the prefix matched with the regex, since with [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) you can specify a capturing group and extract just its contents.

```sql
SELECT regexp_substr(my_field, 'ABC\\s+DEF\\s+(\\S+)', 1, 1, 'e') FROM my_table
```

This is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fr2lU8/1).

*Details*:

- `ABC\s+DEF\s+(\S+)` - `ABC`, one or more whitespaces, `DEF`, one or more whitespaces (this text is just matched) and then one or more non-whitespace chars are *captured* into Group 1 (note you need to double escape backslashes as the single backslash is used to form string escape sequences, and to introduce a literal `\` it needs doubling)
- `1` - start searching from the first char in the string
- `1` - tells the regex engine to extract the first occurrence of the pattern
- `'e'` - enables extraction of the subexpression (aka *capturing group* value) from the resulting match.

Comment: I would just use `'ABC +DEF +(\\S+)'` or even  `'ABC +DEF +([^ ]+)'`, because that's all that's needed and readability counts, but good answer.

Comment: Awesome solution! In the event that I want to get every pattern occurrence in the string, what would I use instead of `1`?

Comment: @RicardoFrancois There is no such a functionality in Amazon Redshift SQL `REGEXP_SUBSTR`. You would need to try out workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=ABC DEF)\s+\S+` or `(?<=ABC DEF)\\s+\\S+` for string literal used in other language.

Trim the leading whitespaces, then you'll get the final output.

Some notes:

1. `(?<=pattern)` is positive lookbehind, it works like normal regex but **won't be put into match result**, place it before strings that you want to match.
2. in most platform, `pattern` in lookbehind doesn't support `*` and `+`. For example, `(?<=ABC DEF\s+)` is unsupported in most cases, you need to move `\s+` outside to match whitespaces and trim them later, check [Important Notes About Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
3. Don't know what pattern `{my_variable_length_keyword}` has though, but it seems it doesn't contain whitespaces, `\S` can match one non-whitespace character.